# Mercurial : using general web.confg

Tags: mercurial, web-config

We are using Mercurial for .Net Mvc applications.
When we merge our branch we are faced with the problem that in web.config we have a different connection string

e.g.

```
connectionString="data source=Dev1\MSSQLSERVER2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf; User ID=sa; Password=pass1
```

Second web.config

```
connectionString="data source=Dev2\MSSQLSERVER2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf; User ID=sa; Password=pass2
```

etc.

How we can merge our configs without editing and rewriting the config again and again.
Just ignoring the web.config file doesn't help.
Does Mercurial have an "ignore file section" option?

Comment: You say: "Just ignoring the web.config file doesn't help". Why isn't is enough to ignore this file? Keep in mind that you have to `hg forget` this file so that it is ignored by mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation: Local configuration that I want to prevent from propagating, but I want to be able to push and pull the same files. Instead of messing with patches, I've been doing it as follows:

Let's say the regular takes place in branch `default` (there could be multiple branches; this is just for concreteness).

1. Update to a clean latest version of `default`, without config state.
2. Create a new branch, `local`. In this branch, commit all the local configuration as one or more changesets.
3. At the tip of `local`, create a new branch, `dev`. Develop your new feature here.

   Your history now looks like this:

   ```
   ...o--o      (default)
          \
           L--L    (local)
               \
                d--d--d  (dev)
   ```
4. When you're ready to push, rebase the entire `dev` branch onto the tip of `default`:

   ```
   hg rebase --source "min(branch('dev'))" --dest default --detach
   ```

   If your feature has its own branch name that you want to keep, add `--keepbranches` to the `rebase` options. The previous tree becomes:

   ```
   ...o--o--d--d--d   (default)
          \
           L--L    (local)
   ```
5. You can now publish the new features with `push -r default` without dragging along the local revisions. (Never merge from `local` *into* `default`; only the other way around). If you forget to say `-r default` when pushing, no problem: Your push gets rejected since it would add a new head.
6. Still on the development server, merge the rebased revs into `local`:

   ```
   ...o--o--d--d--d   (default)
          \        \
           L--L-----N    (local)
   ```
7. You can now create a new `dev` branch on top of `local`, and continue development.

This way my local configuration is under source contol; if it conflicts with a new feature, I can resolve it like any other merge. And if something should go wrong, I can update back to *configured* older versions.

My case also involves configured clones under revision management. You can see the full solution in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988934/699305)

Answer (score 1):

Not a Mercurial answer but can't you change the connection strings to refer to `localhost` instead of `Dev1` and `Dev2`?  You'd also need to change to Windows authentication so that you don't need to have a password in the config file.

That's how we do it in our team and we never have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and create (one or two) patches, which convert *identical, common for both branches* vanilla web.config into branch-specific state